# Number of quadrilaterals formed by 11 points located on 2 parallel lines

Tags: algebra-precalculus, combinations

> We're given two parallel lines $r$ and $s$. Line $r$ contains 5 points and line $s$ 6 points. Considering only those $11$ points, how many quadrilaterals with vertices on those points can be formed?

**My answer:**

Maybe I am being too simplistic but what I thought was that I had to choose 2 points from $r$ and two from $s$ so

$$
\text{Two points from }r \Rightarrow \binom{5}{1} \cdot \binom{4}{1}\\
\text{Two points from }s \Rightarrow \binom{6}{1} \cdot \binom{5}{1}
$$

That said, the total number of possibilities is

$$
\binom{5}{1} \cdot \binom{4}{1} \cdot \binom{6}{1} \cdot \binom{5}{1} = 600
$$

Which does not match with the textbook's answer. Am I making a careless mistake somewhere? Or considering some cases more than one time?

**Textbook's answer: $150$**

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing two points from $r$ gives you $5\choose2$ choices, and not ${5\choose1}{4\choose1}$ . Indeed, let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ and $E$ be the points on $r$. By choosing 1 among 5 and then 1 among the four remaining, you count both $(A, C)$ and $(C, A)$ (which would, in some sense, give you the same quadrilateral).

Thus you only have ${6\choose2} {5\choose2} = 150$ quadrilaterals.
(this is however debatable, it is only true if you only consider simple (ie non-self-crossing) quadrilaterals)

Comment: Hi Astyx, I see, thank you for explaining. One question though: on those 150 shapes are convex and concave quadrilaterals, right? Or only convexes?

Comment: There are 150 group of four vertices where 2 come from $r$ and 2 from $s$. However with 4 vertices one can build 3 different quadrilaterals.

Indeed name $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ your four vertices. You may have the quadrilaterals $ABCD$, $ABDC$ and $ACBD$ (and only one is convex).

Thus there are 150 convex quadrilaterals, and 450 possible quadrilaterals where 2 points come from $r$ and 2 from $s$

Comment: I just realised I confused convex and simple, there are 150 simple quadrilaterals and 300 complex (ie self-crossing) quadrilaterals